# AngularJS's html5Mode adds "#.U44k6nKSyyk" at the end of the URL and messes all the project up [AddThis "data_track_addressbar" option conflict]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-loop, addthis

I meet a strange issue when trying to convert the URL `http://localhost:8080/myProject/#/me` with AngularJS's html5mode (v1.2.1). The server is implemented using Spring MVC.

I have the following base set:

```xml
<base href="http://localhost:8080/myProject/" />
```

When I enable AngularJS's html5Mode:

```js
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

And navigate through:

```
http://localhost:8080/myProject/me
```

Everything seems to work as expected during the first seconds.

But then, the URL automatically get transformed to:

```
http://localhost:8080/myProject/me#.U44k6nKSyyk
```

And in the JavaScript's console, I get the following error repeated many times (just as if stuck in an infinite loop):

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 7; oldVal: 6","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/player.html\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/filters.html\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/videos.html\"; oldVal: undefined"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 8; oldVal: 7","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/player.html\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/filters.html\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/videos.html\"; oldVal: undefined"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 9; oldVal: 8","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/player.html\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/filters.html\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/videos.html\"; oldVal: undefined"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 10; oldVal: 9","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/player.html\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/filters.html\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/videos.html\"; oldVal: undefined"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 11; oldVal: 10","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/player.html\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/filters.html\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: sceParseAsTrusted; newVal: \"static-1.0.0.2/html/videos.html\"; oldVal: undefined"]]
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$rootScope/infdig[...]
    at lowercase (http://localhost:18080/myProject/static-1.0.0.2/lib/angularjs-1.2.1/angular.js:78:12)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:18080/myProject/static-1.0.0.2/lib/angularjs-1.2.1/angular.js:11472:19)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:18080/myProject/static-1.0.0.2/lib/angularjs-1.2.1/angular.js:11682:24)
    at done (http://localhost:18080/myProject/static-1.0.0.2/lib/angularjs-1.2.1/angular.js:7699:45)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:18080/myProject/static-1.0.0.2/lib/angularjs-1.2.1/angular.js:7865:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:18080/myProject/static-1.0.0.2/lib/angularjs-1.2.1/angular.js:7821:11)
```

I used [Tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) server-side:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN" "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>

    <rule>
        <from>^/me</from>
        <to>/</to>
    </rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

What's strange is that, when I comment the `.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');` line, the `#/me` URL behaves as expected (no error, no extra URL suffix...).

Any idea where this issue could come from? Don't hesitate to ask me more details on some points if you have a hunch `;)`

Comment: just a try ^^ may be there are conflicts between client and server side I mean angular don't need a rewrite rule for html5Mode enable at least if you are not using a seo hook but even in this cas e you need something to return always the index page https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

Comment: @Whisher The rewrite rules are used to tell the server not to intertept the `/me` URL (it returns a 404 otherwise, see https://github.com/bdunklau/LittleBlueBird/wiki/URL-Rewriting-and-HTML5-in-AngularJS).

Comment: I know what rewrite rules are may be you have not got my point ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow...

I added long ago [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) to my project, and had the [`data_track_addressbar` option](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381254-address-bar-sharing-analytics#.U5BywYcbP4Y) set to `true`.

The `#.U44k6nKSyyk` suffix I noticed was actually the AddThis *semi-random value which identifies each page view*.

There must be a conflict between this AddThis `data_track_addressbar` option and AngularJS's html5Mode, since when disabling the option, everything works finally as expected... What an absurd bug!

If anyone understands why, I would be interested into an explication `;)`